# Get location updates android

Tags: java, android, location, locationmanager

In my app I am getting user location in background through a service,the service is running even app is killed but it can not retrieve user's location.

I am using locationmanager for retrieving location updates as follows.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    1000,1f,locationListener);
```

I am listening location updates in listeners overrided method as follows:

```
@Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    Log.e("JK-->>","location updated by gpsping service-->> "+location.getLatitude()+
                            " "+location.getLongitude());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Location changed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```